# Does Android Studio have something similar to Xcode's quick jump bar and MARK:-

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, comments

I'm just getting into Android Studio and I know it has `NOTE:` (not sure what to call it). I've seen it inside the `build.gradle` file.

In a Xcode file I can add in `Mark:-` to break my code into sections with **lines above each section** so that when I tap the `quick jump bar` those marked sections will stand out:

```
// MARK:- Properties

// MARK:- View Controller Lifecycle

// MARK:- Helper Functions
```

[image]

[image]

**Is there a way to do this inside Android Studio AND how would I view it similar to how Xcode's quick jump bar works?**

Comment: Something similar would be structure option from Android Studio. Not sure if you exactly want that thing but it shows you structure of file. shortcut would be (Alt+7).

Comment: thanks, Im on a mac and tried **option** + **7** and nothing happened. I then went to **Help** and typed **structure** which brought me to **File Structure** (Navigate >  File Structure. It's similar to the **quick jump bar** but it shows everything in alphabetical order instead of sections

Comment: @JeelVankhede **region**/**endregion** and **cmmd** + **7** was what I was looking for. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe, you're looking for [regions](https://android.jlelse.eu/create-regions-in-android-studio-55333a1ad8a1) ?

```
//region YourRegionName

//code here

//endregion
```

in conjunction with Android Studio's Structure View (ALT+7/CMD+7), this might be what you're looking for

[image]

created with simply:

```
class MyExampleClass {

//region Method one

//code here

// endregion

// region Method two

//code here

// endregion

// region Method three

//code here

// endregion
}
```